# Скрыть способ доставки в зависимости от способа оплаты

Tags: php, woocommerce, ms-word

Всем доброго дня. В сети много примеров кода, где прячут способ оплаты в зависимости от выбранной доставки, а у меня обратная ситуация. Если пользователь выбирает какой-то способ оплаты (наложка), то нужно прятать способ доставки (курьер). Это реально сделать вставкой кода в function.php, если да, может кто пример подскажет?

Comment: Вы бы для начала сами привели пример своего кода... У вас с помощью PHP выбирается способ оплаты? Т.е. страница перезагружается каждый раз? То что вы описали, проще сделать средствами JS, а в PHP уже проверять не были ли изменены данные (на тот случай если пользователь попытается обмануть, и со стороны клиента отправит неверный способ доставки)

Comment: Никакого кода у меня нет. Методы доставки и оплаты выводятся плагинами.

Comment: Вот как выглядят эти выводы и хотелось бы узнать. CSS-классы их контейнеров в частности.